# ESLint: Unexpected property "indent" in eslintrc

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, indentation, eslintrc

As documented [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent), there is an ESLint property for indentation called `indent`. The example looks like this:

> Or for tabbed indentation:
>
> ```
> {
>     "indent": ["error", "tab"]
> }
> ```

However, if I paste this exact code into my `.eslintrc` file, VS Code shows this as an error:

> ESLint: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc is invalid: - Unexpected top-level property "indent". . Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details.

The `.eslintrc` file that I had before has a number of rules already, and there are no errors printed with those. If I add `"indent"` to that list, or by itself, it fails.

Here is the error and stack trace printed in the ESLint output channel in VS Code:

> ```
> [Error - 10:38:55 PM] ESLint stack trace:
> [Error - 10:38:55 PM] Error: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc is invalid:
>     - Unexpected top-level property "indent".
>     at validateConfigSchema (/home/aaronfranke/workspace/OddJobs/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/config-validator.js:286:15)
>     at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeConfigData (/home/aaronfranke/workspace/OddJobs/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:469:9)
>     at ConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigDataInDirectory (/home/aaronfranke/workspace/OddJobs/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:445:33)
>     at ConfigArrayFactory.loadInDirectory (/home/aaronfranke/workspace/OddJobs/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:401:18)
>     at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (/home/aaronfranke/workspace/OddJobs/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:305:46)
>     at CascadingConfigArrayFactory.getConfigArrayForFile (/home/aaronfranke/workspace/OddJobs/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:250:18)
>     at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/home/aaronfranke/workspace/OddJobs/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cli-engine.js:860:47)
>     at /home/aaronfranke/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-1.9.1/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:60107
>     at /home/aaronfranke/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-1.9.1/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:61116
> ```

What's going on? Is this option not valid somehow? Is the example config wrong? Is there something wrong with my [ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)? Is there something wrong with VS Code? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Linux 64-bit with VS Code 1.40.1, ESLint extension 1.9.1, and `eslint --version` is `v5.16.0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not allowed to put this settings as a top level property, which means it has to be nested in another property, which is `"rules"`. So you have to write it like this:

```
{
    //... other stuff ...

    "rules": {
        "indent": [ "error", "tab" ]
    }
}
```